# How to make Visual Studio not put { on a new line?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, formatting, if-statement

If I have code like this

```
if(true){
```

and I add

```
}
```

it is transformed into

```
if (true)
{
}
```

but I would like it to stay in format

```
if (true) {
}
```

Even if I copy code that has `if` like this, it is transformed into the longer version.

P.S. I understand that it's a C++ and C# standard to use the longer version, however I do come from a different standard, and it's easier for me to use the shorter version.

**I bet there is some formatter option that can be turned off or changed.**

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting-> New Lines

Here there are a lot of options. Remove the check on **all** options here to never put the open bracket on a new line.

**EDIT**

The section `New Line Options for expressions` does not relate to placement of code in conjunction with brackets, so those you don't need to touch.

Comment: +1 thank you. However, when I turn those off, and then deliberately put the brace on the new line, it moves it back to the same line :( Is there a ways to stop it meddling in things I didn't ask it to fiddle with?

Comment: What monster would enable new lines by default?

Comment: I'm using VS2019 preview, and I had to make the change and then exit Visual Studio completely and reopen it in order for the change to stick. If I just changed it then tried to reformat the document, it would just reset to the previous settings.

Comment: For Visual Studio Code go File -> Preferences -> Settings and under Extensions choose the language you want to change properties. Search for  `Clang_format_fallback Style` (e.g.: for C++ `C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style`) and change the value from `Visual Studio` to `Google`

Comment: Thank you! This is one of the most rage inducing features of Visual Studio for Unity.

Comment: To be clear, the options that effect the if statement are...
         "Place brace on a new line for CONTROL BLOCKS" 
and  "Place else on a new line"

Answer (score 34):

Bear in mind that if you're using Resharper the above procedure won't help, since Resharper overrides the native VS behavior. If that's your case go to Resharper > Options, Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Braces Layout, set all top "Braces Layout" options to "At end of line (K&R style)".

Took me a while to figure this out, so I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 17):

For all the Mac Users out there, this is how I solved it:

Preferences -> Source Code -> Code Formatting -> C# source code -> C# Format -> Edit

There you can change it under the Category: New Lines

[image: image example]

Answer (score 13):

You can change that in the options of your Visual Studio. Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> formatting -> new lines (or something similar, I only have the german version of visual studio). You can then change where you want to put the brackets into the next line and where you don't. Personally, I removed all the options, but if you want to have a new line e.g. in loops, there are many options to customize this.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at `Tools -> Options` then `Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines`

Answer (score 1):

For C++, the only way I can avoid VC++ putting '{' on new line for namespaces is by unchecking "Automatically format block when I type a }" option:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To do the same thing for CSS you have to go to: `Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS > Advanced > Formatting > Automatic Formatting > Off`

[image: CSS Auto Formatting Off]